# How to get index of input in javascript - can use jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays, input

I have an array of inputs generated from js code. I have set the name of the inputs like this: `name="myTextInput[]"`

How can I get the index of the selected input?

I tried something like:

```
 onClick="oc(this);"
```

where:

```
function oc(inp)
{
    return(inp.index);
}
```

but is not working.

I can use jQuery as well

Comment: You're not using jQuery in your sample code. Do you want to?

Comment: In the future, please try to provide a complete code sample so that we understand exactly what you're working on and what you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the EACH function in jquery.  This will parse through the set of matched elements.  You can put a custom function inside that will use the index of each element, as you parse through, as an argument.

```
$('input').each(function(index){
    alert(index);
});
```

You can also get the value of each input like this:

```
$('input').each(function(index, val){
    alert(index + ' has value: ' + val);
});
```

see details here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

** EDIT **

If you want the value shown in an alert box on click, use the each function and the click function together.  Remember to get the real-time value of the input, use `$(this).val()`. Return index and value data on click:

```
$('input').each(function(index, val){
    $(this).click(function(){
        alert(index + ' has value: ' + $(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: I thought the OP was looking to do this `onclick`, not as part of an `each()` function.  If you're going to loop, you might consider a simple `for(...)` structure.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the input like this *(not sure if you actually wanted the `click` event though)*...

```
var inputs = $('input[name="myTextInput[]"]');

inputs.click(function() {
    alert(inputs.index(this));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the `index()` method to find the position of an element.

Check out this example: http://jsbin.com/uyucuv/edit#javascript,html

```
<ul>
  <li id="foo">foo</li>
  <li id="bar">bar</li>
  <li id="baz">baz</li>
</ul>


$(function() {
  $("li").on("click", function() {
    alert($(this).index());
  });
});
```

Check the `index()` documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/index/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The "jQuery way" is to avoid `onClick="whatever()"` and use pure JavaScript separate from the HTML tags. Try this between a pair of `<script>` tags (note: requires jQuery 1.7 or higher):

```
$('input').on('click', function() {
    var varname = $(this).attr('name'),
        $arr = $('input[name="'+varname+'"]'),
        idx = $arr.index(this);

    alert(idx);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/EK4xC/